# How to use apollo-link-rest to query array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to use apollo-link-rest to query this dictionary API - https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/test.

The API returns an array of objects which are the definition of the words but for some reason I can't structure my gql query properly to return a result.

My query is like so:

```
const Query = gql`
  query Definitions {
    definitions @rest(type: "Definition", path: "test") {
      results @rest(type: "Word") {
        word
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

And I have setup my `restLink` like so:

```
const restLink = new RestLink({ 
  uri: "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en" 
});
```

However, when I log my result, I end up with this:

```
const {
  data,
  error,
  loading
} = useQuery(Query, {
  variables: {
    searchInput: "test"
  }
});

console.log("res:", {
  data,
  error,
  loading
}) // {"data": {"definitions": null}, "error": undefined, "loading": false}
```

I was expecting:

```
{"data": {"definitions": [{word: "test", ...}]}, "error": undefined, "loading": false}
```

I feel like my GQL query doesn't match the expected response of the rest API but I am unsure what this should look like considering the response is an array of data. Perhaps I need to set the types to something else?

How can I structure my query so that I can get the expected array response my the dictionary API?